# Extract Clojure string up to colon

Tags: regex, string, clojure

I have a string "Breakfast: eggs & bacon @ll day!" and I'd like to extract everything up to the colon. I'd like to get back just "Breakfast".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Try using [split](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.string/split) to split the string on the colon, and then get the first element of the result.

```
(clojure.string/split "Breakfast: eggs & bacon @ll day" #":")
```

`split` is likely the best option for you rather than using a regex with capture groups. You can also split on any regex you'd like, so if you want to split on something more complex, that is an option.

Answer (score 4):

Adam's answer is preferable for a task like this. If you want to use regular expression, you could use [`re-find`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/re-find).

```
> (re-find #"^[^:]+"  "Breakfast: eggs & bacon @ll day!")
Breakfast
```

The regular expression uses a negation class to match everything up until the colon. If the regex contains no parenthesized capturing groups, then on a match re-find returns the part of the string that matches.

Comment: This is a great solution too.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to have everything AFTER the colon instead? I'm curious to see how the regex changes.

Comment: interesting.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Regex, I recommend txt2re.com. You can enter your string, and click on the part you'd like to pick out. txt2re will then generate a Regex for you Many languages are supported, e.g. direct Perl/PHP output to match the string.

It's interesting to see in what way a Regex changes if you select another part of your text. You can learn (simple) Regex applications there, by playing around with the tool.